# Ошибка 400 (Bad Request) в AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Клиентская

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/getlisteat',
    chache: false

});
</script>
```

Серверная:

```
    public function actionGetlisteat()
    {


        $file = json_decode(

file_get_contents('../use_config/config.json'), true)['eat'];
        return json_encode($file);
    }
```

Comment: сделайте вместо return, echo.

Comment: это в  yii контроллерах, но все же попробовал, но не сработало

Comment: `actionGetlisteat` ->`actionPostlisteat` || `type: 'POST'` -> `type: 'GET'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в Ajax POST. Способ получения данных для метода контроллера не задан, стало быть, по умолчанию - GET. Нужно согласовать

Comment: да да, так сработало

Comment: а как можно задать способ получение данных как вы написали?, можете пнуть в источник где это явление написано

Comment: У Вас php? http://javascript.ru/blog/gordon-freeman/primery-raboty-s-ajax-otpravka-get-post-head-zaprosov-cherez-ajax-javascript

Comment: да, не нравится мне то что тут длина комментарии должно быть больше 15 символов)

Answer (score -1):

Вот мой вариант:

```
chache == cache ? true : false )
```

Comment: )), но все равно)